# Opening of new tab when user click on a button provided on popup using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

There is  a question regarding Selenium WebDriver given is a scenario

1. I login to the application
2. Click on some link
3. It opens a new popup which has iframe
4. There is a preview button on this popup on which if I click manually it opens a new tab in the previous parent window but if I click on this button using selenium webdriver it opens new window
5. I want to open new tab using selenium webdriver by clicking on this preview button any solution?

Comment: Selenium Webdriver API probably does not have support for handling tabs.

Comment: What language binding you are using? Pop up handler works differently depending on language

Comment: Facing the same problem. Got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

These are steps you should take then.

- Log into application
- Get current window handles
- Find a list of window handles EXCEPT currentWindow handles
- `switchTo()` newly opened window handle, `switchTo()` `iframe`
- Click the button inside an `iframe`
- Get the window handles again
- `switchTo()` newly opened window
- perform some action, close all window except parent.

A sample can look like the following. *Note: C# code*

```
public void PopupWindowHandle()
{
    //logged into application
    //get current window handle
    string prentWindowHandle = Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

    //click should generate a new tab
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("id")).Click();

    //get window handle counts. In your case should be 2
    List<string> windowHandles = Driver.WindowHandles.ToList();

    //switchTo newly opened window handle
    foreach (string handle in windowHandles)
    {
        if (handle != prentWindowHandle)
        {
            Driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            //switch focus into iframe
            Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("Iframe Selector")));
            //click should generate another window
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("id")).Click();

            //should be 2 in total
            List<string> newHandles = Driver.WindowHandles.ToList();

            foreach (string newHandle in newHandles)
            {
                if (newHandle != handle)
                {
                    Driver.SwitchTo().Window(newHandle);
                    //do some work
                    Driver.Close();
                    Driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
                    break;
                }
            }

            Driver.Close();
            Driver.SwitchTo().Window(prentWindowHandle);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code does not deal the popup I am talking about it a fancy popup like most of the webapps are using now a days so switching to that popup is obtained by switchto.frame call but when I click on the button available on popup it opens new window I want to open new tab on this button click along with parent window

Comment: @Mubbashir... The word popup is not helpful to someone does not have any idea about your application. What kind of pop up you are talking about? I initially thought a pop up window as you mentioned in the original post.

Comment: yes  my bad! let me re-phrase my scenario
1: main window has link and I click on that link
2: it opens up new iframe popup having preview button
3: I click on preview button and it opens a new window instead i want to open new tab with parent window and want to switch control on that tab

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not using chrome.:)
Usually, webdriver forces a browser to open a new window instead of a tab, it's easier to dealing with through switch window. Like IE and Firefox, but chrome will open a new tab instead of a new window and it still supports switch window. This how I found, try it out.

Comment: Nope, I am using firefox

Comment: So you can just let it open as a new window and then deal it with switching windows.

Comment: No when I perform it manually  when I click on the button available on popup it opens a new tab in the parent window behind the popup

the main problem is that I can switch to this popup using only frame tag and cannot get the handle of this popup i really don't know why

Comment: can you post some code and explain what happen to the steps? I get a little confused.

Comment: driver.get("http://abcportal/");
  String pwin= driver.getWindowHandle();
 //login code
 
  //following click will open a popup having iframe not window and I am unable find its handle
  
  driver.findElement(By.id("id")).click();
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("id")));
  
  //following click will open new window It should be open along with parent tab behind the popup
  //but its opening new window and and I want to switch to this window
 
  driver.findElement(By.id("id")).click();

Comment: Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

   for(String phandle : windowHandles )
   {
    if(!pwin.equals(phandle))
    {
     driver.switchTo().window(phandle);driver.close();
    } 
   
   }

Comment: Hi, please refer to this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/selenium-developer-activity/tab|sort:relevance/selenium-developer-activity/-yO_Z0pqi_0/EiVn-zeL29IJ , firefoxdriver doesn't support to deal with tab,  so no matter how it behaves when u do it manually, it forces to open a new window instead a tab. This is how firefoxdriver designed.

Comment: its 3 years old post what do you say about it, hasn't it been implemented yet?

Comment: Yes, 3 years old already, means the develop team already known this and It will not be implemented. It's by design.